# Создание обучаемого чат бота на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот

Хочу сделать чат бота на python, в идеале он должен получать вопрос, и отвечать, как записано в БД, к примеру, если пользователь задает "который час", "сколько сейчас времени", "время" и т.д. Все это относится к вопросам вида "сейчас время" и ответ будет time().now().

Как бот может отвечать на один вопрос заданный по разному? Какую библиотеку использовать, или что прочитать что бы понять как это реализовать? 
Заранее огромное спасибо!

P.S. Знаю про DialogFlow, но очень хочется реализовать это вручную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите тут разбирают как делают таких ботов.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClnuFk7UuX8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XrMmNS8zSKE